# TileMap not not rendering

Tags: java, tilemap

I have a tile map that I would like to be able to move while playing the game. In the code you will see the posX and posY variables. I used these variables so that when I complete this, I can have the player control movement via the map like in early Final Fantasy games(1-6). The problem is that it is currently not rendering. It was rendering just fine when I was using the x and y variables from the loop, but I need to be able to move the map around, and I don't know how I would achieve this using the loop variables. I debugged the file and all the variables were updating correctly, so I don't know why it's not rendering in the correct place.

```
public class TileMapEditor
{   
   BufferedImage[] tiles = new BufferedImage[19];

   //array of tile types
   int[][] map = new int[32][32];
   //position coordinates
   public static int posX, posY;

   public TileMapEditor(int posX, int posY) throws IOException
   {
       int x = 0, y = 0;
       this.posX = posX;
       this.posY = posY;
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res/tileMap2.txt"));

       String line;

       while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
       {
           String[] values = line.split(",");

           for(String str : values)
           {
               int str_int = Integer.parseInt(str);
               map[x][y] = str_int;
               System.out.print(map[x][y] + " ");
               y += 1;
           }
           System.out.println("");
           x += 1;
           y = 0;
       }

       in.close();
   }

   public void update()
   {
   }

   public void render(Graphics g)
   {
       for(int x = 0; x < 32; x++)
       {       
           for(int y = 0; y < 32; y++)
           {
               int textureType = map[x][y];
               BufferedImage texture = tiles[textureType]; 
               setTile();
               g.drawImage(texture, posX * 32, posY * 32, null);
               posY += 32;
           }
           posX += 32;
           posY = -Game.HEIGHT / 2;
       }
   }

   public void setTile()
   {
       tiles[0] = Assets.grass;
       tiles[1] = Assets.dirt;
       tiles[2] = Assets.water;
       tiles[3] = Assets.tree;
       tiles[4] = Assets.multiTree;
       tiles[5] = Assets.NSpath;
       tiles[6] = Assets.uprtPath;
       tiles[7] = Assets.EWpath;
       tiles[8] = Assets.upltPath;
       tiles[9] = Assets.dnltPath;
       tiles[10] = Assets.dnrtPath;
       tiles[11] = Assets.watgrsdn;
       tiles[12] = Assets.watgrslt;
       tiles[13] = Assets.watgrsup;
       tiles[14] = Assets.watgrsrt;
       tiles[15] = Assets.watgrsSE;
       tiles[16] = Assets.watgrsSW;
       tiles[17] = Assets.watgrsNW;
       tiles[18] = Assets.watgrsNE;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem is in `g.drawImage(texture, posX * 32, posY * 32, null);`

In your loops, it looks like you are manually incrementing posX, and posY.  The `posX * 32` and `posY * 32` should probably be `posX` and `posY`.

`g.drawImage(texture, posX, posY, null);`

Either that, or if you want to use the x and y values of your loops then it should be:
`g.drawImage(texture, x * 32, y * 32, null);`